# The canvas overlaps my button

Tags: javascript, css, html

Here are my code snippet:

```
<canvas id ="compound_area"  style= "position: absolute; border: 2px hidden; top:70px; left: 10px; background-color : #FFFF99"  width = "1230"  height= "580"></canvas> 

<canvas id ="drawing_plate"  style= "position: absolute; border: 2px hidden; top:93px; left: 230px; background-color : #FFFFFF" width = "1000" height= "550">

<button id= "pencil" style= "position: absolute; top: 76px; left: 17px"> PENCIL </button>
```

I can see one canvas overlaps another one partially. And that's what I need. 
But as I need to add a button above the yellow canvas (background). I just can't find the method. Even if I use relative:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<canvas id ="compound_area"  style= "position: absolute; z-index= 0; border: 2px hidden; margin-top:70px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right : 10px; margin-bottom : 10px; background-color : #FFFF99 "   width = "1230"  height = "580"></canvas> 

<canvas id ="drawing_plate"  style= "position: absolute; z-index= 1; border: 2px hidden; margin-top:93px; margin-left: 230px; margin-bottom : 20px; background-color : #FFFFFF" width = "1000" height= "550"></canvas>

<button id= "pencil" style= "position: absolute; z-index= 2; top: 76px; left: 17px"> PENCIL </button>
</div>
```

The button is always behind the canvas. 
I'm a new beginner and try many methods but in vain. Please somebody help me. 
Thank u.

Comment: Depends really on what you want. Might be that I'm too tired today, but I have no clue what the hell you are talking about.

Comment: The button can't be above the yellow canvas, only yellow canvas overlaps it. Got that?

Comment: Have you tried `z-index:2;` instead of `z-index=2;`? (CSS syntax is `property:value`, not `property=value`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But [...] I need to add a button above the yellow canvas (background)

So why are you positioning the button at `top: 76px`, and the canvas at `top: 70px`? You are explicitly positioning the button under the canvas.

Change you button code to something like this:

```
<button id= "pencil" style= "position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 17px"> PENCIL </button>
```

Comment: It's not clear whether OP wants the button above in terms of z-based (`z-index`) or y-based positioning (`top`). I *guess* he used the rule `top:76px` on purpose and needs layer based help. He should really clarify this issue :/.